# Running multiple query on one command in

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on stationery management application where i receives the stationery and issue the stationery.

I have two tables

- tblstationerytype keeps the value of stock
- tblstationerystock   keeps record of  all the transactions(issued or received)

I have a php page in which on submit button it  it inserts the record in transaction table  and same time update the balance status on the first table.I have the following code It is only inserting the value on transaction table  it does not update the record on first table (balance) my code is

```
  for($i=0; $i<$samplecount; $i++){
    $txntype="received";    
    $orderno=$_POST['orderno'];
    $orderdate=$_POST["orderdate"];
    $stationerytype=$_POST['stationerytype'];
    $stationeryqtyrecd=$_POST['stationeryqtyrecd'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO  tblstationerystock(txntype,orderno,orderdate,stationerytype,stationeryqtyrecd) VALUES(:txntype,:orderno,:orderdate,:stationerytype,:stationeryqtyrecd)";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':txntype',$txntype,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':orderno',$orderno,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':orderdate',$orderdate,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':stationerytype',$stationerytype[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':stationeryqtyrecd',$stationeryqtyrecd[$i],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    
    $sql="
    UPDATE tblstationerytype s
      JOIN 
         ( SELECT stationerytype
                , SUM(CASE WHEN txntype = 'received' THEN stationeryqtyrecd ELSE -stationeryqtyrecd END) balance
             FROM tblstationerystock
            GROUP 
               BY stationerytype
         ) t 
        ON t.stationerytype = s.stationerytype
       SET s.balance = t.balance;";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
```

Comment: so you are updating every record in tblstationerytype? how many rows does it have?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It will have around 25 (total number of stationery type) but transaction table  will have lot of lines

Comment: and this whole lot is going to be examined on the every update

Comment: @YourCommonSense  My basic aim can be explained by following example . Suppose I receives 50  pen ,so i will make  a entry or receiving 50 pen in my transaction table. & it will show the balance 50 pen in my first table.if some one request for the issue of 10 pen. It will make entry to issue of 10 pen and same time it will update the balance in first as 40 (50-10).

Comment: @YourCommonSense any other idea except abovewill be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question under different user names?